# Where is the shader packs folder on Mac?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, macos

I had downloaded some shader packs before, but now I can't find my shader packs folder. I am on a Mac.

Comment: The easiest method would be: Open the resource packs folder inside of Minecraft itself, go up one folder and look for `shaderpacks`. If you are using Optifine's shader implementation, it even offers a shader pack folder button to click on.

Answer (score 1):

The shader packs folder on a Mac is `~/library/application support/minecraft/shaderpacks`. (`~` stands for your user folder and will be automatically replaced with your userfolder when using <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)

However, you can also get to the shader packs folder by going to `Options... > Video Settings... --> Shaders... --> Open shader packs folder`.